# Different formatting buttons in the same Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2010 on two machines installed from the same DVD.

The "HTML source editing" panel in both studios has a formatting button, but this is not the same button although its icon looks similar.

For one Studio it is a "Format the whole document. (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D)" button, for other - "Format the currently selected text. (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F)".

How could this difference come up if no third party plug-ins were installed and no buttons were customized in both cases?

May be there is some setting which controls behaviour of this button?

I can remember such a difference between two copies of VS2005 and VS2008 too.

Comment: When you first run VS, it asks you which settings you want to use. Was the same selection made in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings that you use can affect the default views, buttons and key-bindings.

[Visual Studio Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/zbhkx167%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> When you first start Visual Studio, you are required to select a settings collection that contains predefined settings designed to match your development habits. If you upgrade to another edition of Visual Studio, you are also given the option of applying the other edition's settings using the My Previous Settings option.

and:

> Settings are customizations to the IDE, such as window layouts, editor defaults, and available dialog box options that you can save, export, import, or reset to make the IDE easier to use.
>
> Your active settings consist of two parts: predefined customizations from the installed .vssettings file you selected the first time you started Visual Studio and any subsequent IDE customizations you have made.

Comment: How to re-run this startup configuration wizard?

Comment: @Paul - Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all Settings

Comment: Thank you, it helped to choose "General development settings".